# sessionStateChanged ios 6 facebook sdk 3.1

Tags: objective-c, ios, facebook, ios6, facebook-login

I am implementing the following code to check the status of my Facebook session in the application

```
    - (void)sessionStateChanged:(FBSession *)session
                      state:(FBSessionState) state
                      error:(NSError *)error
{
    switch (state) {
        case FBSessionStateOpen:
                    if (!error) {
                        // We have a valid session
                        NSLog(@"User session found");

                        [self reautorizarPermisos:self ];
                    }

        break;
        case FBSessionStateClosed:
                    NSLog(@"sesion close");
                    [self    loginFB:self  ];

        break;
        case FBSessionStateClosedLoginFailed:

                    NSLog(@"sesssion failed");

                    [FBSession.activeSession closeAndClearTokenInformation];
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
     postNotificationName:UIDocumentStateChangedNotification
     object:session];

    if (error) {
        UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                                  initWithTitle:@"Error"
                                  message:error.localizedDescription
                                  delegate:nil
                                  cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                  otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alertView show];
    }
}
```

This code was accessed from here
[facebook documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/login-with-facebook-using-ios-sdk/)

and I'm calling the method as follows

```
- (IBAction)login:(id)sender {

        FBSession *sesion;
        FBSessionState state;
        NSError *error;

        [self sessionStateChanged:sesion state:state error:error];
        NSLog(@"loginnnnnnn");
    }
```

the problem is that the state did not enter any of the cases, apparently the session is neither open nor closed or failed thank you very much for your help

Comment: why don't you log the value of `state`?

Comment: yes ,the value is 858157003 and no meaning

Comment: That is the integer representation of the enum value. It surely has a meaning, try to compare it against **all** the possible value of that `enum` instead of just 3, as you are doing now. Check my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only want to get the current state of session like active or not then this approach is wrong. As this is a delegate and this only triggers when ever there is a change in the Fbsession.

In order to check the state of the fbsession just do the following code.

```
if (FBSession.activeSession.isOpen)
{
     //Write code to send any message. Here Facebook Session is active
}
else
{
    //Call the Facebook Login page to login into the Facebook and start new session.
}
```

or you can also check the state by using `FBSession.activeSession.accessToken == nil`

Comment: or you can also check the state by using (FBSession.activeSession.accessToken == nil)

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/ios/3.1/class/FBSession#FBSessionState+enum) the possible values for `FBSessionState` are

```
typedef enum {
    FBSessionStateCreated = 0,
    FBSessionStateCreatedTokenLoaded = 1,
    FBSessionStateCreatedOpening = 2,
    FBSessionStateOpen = 1 | FB_SESSIONSTATEOPENBIT,
    FBSessionStateOpenTokenExtended = 2 | FB_SESSIONSTATEOPENBIT,
    FBSessionStateClosedLoginFailed = 1 | FB_SESSIONSTATETERMINALBIT,
    FBSessionStateClosed = 2 | FB_SESSIONSTATETERMINALBIT,
} FBSessionState;
```

In your `switch` you are missing

`FBSessionStateCreated`
`FBSessionStateCreatedTokenLoaded`
`FBSessionStateCreatedOpening`
`FBSessionStateOpenTokenExtended`

so your `state` value is likely to be one of them.